# UrbanAirship notification not sent

Tags: ios, urbanairship.com

I receive this error 
"iOS payload, but nothing to deliver to (missing device_tokens, tags, segments, or aliases)."

When I try to send this payload: 
{"alias": "my_alias", "aps": {"alert": "Besm Allah!"}}

Answer (score 0):

Then you are probably missing those properties in your JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Urbanairship changed the json format without notice.
"alias" now is an array, so {"aliases": ["my_alias"], "aps": {"alert": "Besm Allah!"}} works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Per [this link](https://support.urbanairship.com/entries/70139918-API-FAQs), you need to include this in your HTTP headers:

```
Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;
```

I was getting the same error and adding this header fixed it for me.